# jQuery UI tabs.add() makes TWO tabs, one of which stay in odd position, empty and unused

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

Please let me refer to http://c.lrin.tk.

Code structure:

```
--DIV main_window <-class: ui-tabs
----DIV top_bar
------UL          <-class: ui-tabs-nav
------[1]
----DIV ui-tabs-0
----[2]
```

When you push the "[+]" button at the top to activate a "tabs.add()" event,
you can see that the id of each *shown* tab 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, and so on.

These expected tabs are added at **position [2]** (see *Code structure*),
while a few empty, unused, odd-numbered tabs are added at **position [1]**.

An alike problem was reported as a bug and was fixed in the latest version, but I still gets this.

Somebody said `DIV top_bar` is the criminal, But even after I removed this DIV, the problem still remains.

Any ideas? Please use http://c.lrin.tk as well in your example.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"This is not a bug, this is a feature".

Since you look at HTML, you may notice "ui-widget-**content**" class.
Most tab implementations (actually, all ~10 I met on web) works this way and this is ok. Each tab DOM element have corresponding element for tab content.
Why this one mixes ids for both tab and content elements? Due to implementation.

Comment: So I guess I should just leave it alone?